# MongoDB query to transform documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the documents structured in MongoDB 6.0 as below:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6555a7d7c2d9de74abb09de8"),
        "tagName" : "tag1",
        "tagValue" : "value1",
        "categories" : [
            "Category-1"
        ],
        "otherField1" : [],
        "otherField2" : "something-else-1"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6555a865c2d9de74abb09de9"),
        "tagName" : "tag2",
        "tagValue" : "value2",
        "categories" : [
            "Category-1",
            "Category-2"
        ],
        "otherField1" : [],
        "otherField2" : "something-else-2"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6555c652c2d9de74abb09df2"),
        "tagName" : "tag3",
        "tagValue" : "value3",
        "categories" : [
            "Category-2",
            "Category-3",
        ],
        "otherField1" : [],
        "otherField2" : "something-else-3"
    }
]
```

I would like to transform them as per the below structure.

```
[
    {
        "category" : "Category-1",
        "tags" : [
            {
                "name" : "tag1",
                "value" : "value1"
            },
            {
                "name" : "tag2",
                "value" : "value2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category" : "Category-2",
        "tags" : [
            {
                "name" : "tag2",
                "value" : "value2"
            },
            {
                "name" : "tag3",
                "value" : "value3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category" : "Category-3",
        "tags" : [
            {
                "name" : "tag3",
                "value" : "value3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I used the `$unwind` and `$group` operators but was unable to get the final result.
Any help is appreciated.

PS: At the end, I have to translate the MongoDB query using C#/.NET 7 driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your query should contains `$unwind` and `$group` stages.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$categories"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$categories",
      tags: {
        $push: {
          name: "$tagName",
          value: "$tagValue"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      category: "$_id",
      tags: 1
    }
  }
])
```

---

For the MongoDB .NET Driver syntax, you should create models for the unwind and projection/result.

Example:

```cs
public class RootModel
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string TagValue { get; set; }
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<string> OtherField1 { get; set; }
    public string OtherField2 { get; set; }
}

public class UnwindRootModel
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string TagValue { get; set; }
    public string Categories { get; set; }
    public List<string> OtherField1 { get; set; }
    public string OtherField2 { get; set; }
}

[BsonNoId]
public class ResultModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<TagModel> Tags { get;set; }
}

[BsonNoId]
public class TagModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Before querying from the collection, as your document's fields are in camel case, either you need to specify the field name as camel case to the classes' properties via `[BsonElement]` attribute or you should register the camel case pack.

```cs
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
ConventionRegistry.Register("camel case", pack, t => true);
```

With Aggregate Fluent:

```cs
var result = await _collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind<RootModel, UnwindRootModel>(x => x.Categories)
    .Group(x => x.Categories,
        g => new ResultModel
        {
            Category = g.Key,
            Tags = g.Select(y => new TagModel
            {
                Name = y.TagName,
                Value = y.TagValue
            }).Distinct().ToList()
        })
    .ToListAsync();
```

[image]

If you face difficulties in writing the Aggregate Fluent query, you can provide the raw query with [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/export-query-to-language/).

**Update:** As mentioned by the post owner to remove the duplicate tags, apply `.Distinct()` to the `Tags` list in Aggregate Fluent/LINQ.

Comment: I used $addToSet instead of $push to eliminate duplicate tags. Thanks.

Comment: Ya, alright, in this case you should use `.Distinct()` to eliminate duplicate.